# Why does $F\langle g\rangle\cong F[x]/(x^n-1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

This is example 1 on page 842 of Dummit and Foote. If $g$ is the cyclic group of order $n$, then the group ring over a field $F$ 
$$
F\langle g\rangle\cong F[x]/(x^n-1)
$$

by the surjective homomorphism sending $x^k$ to $g^k$. It's clear to me that $(x^n-1)$ is contained in the kernel, but why is it the whole kernel?

If $\sum_{i=1}^m a_ix^i$ is in the kernel, then sending it to the group ring gives you a sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+a_{i+n}+a_{i+2n}+\cdots+)g^i
$$
after reducing powers of $g$ and collecting coefficients, but where do they go from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't try to show directly that a polynomial with general coefficients lies in the kernel.  Instead, you should use polynomial division to write $p(x) = q(x)(x^n-1)+r(x)$, where $\deg{r(x)} < n$.

Then, all that remains is to show that if $r(x)$ lies in the kernel, $r(x)=0$.  This can be done by looking directly at the coefficients, and using the definition of the group ring.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to consider the *inverse*, mapping $F\langle g\rangle\to F[x]/(x^n-1)$: generated by $g\mapsto x$. You have to check that it is well define, and you're basically done.

Comment: How would you show that it's well-defined?