# $F[G]\simeq F^{\#G}$ as $F$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field containing a primitive $n$-th root of unity and let $G$ be an abelian group of exponent $n$.

We know that $F[G]$ is a free $F$-vector space with basis $G$, how to prove $F[G]\simeq F^{\#G}$ as $F$-algebra?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that we have done this earlier. Anyway $F[G]\simeq F[x]/(x^n-1)$, and $x^n-1$ factors into distinct linear factors over $F$, so the claim follows from the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/643144/11619) is the isomorphism to the quotient of the polynomial algebra. Didn't find this specific use of CRT right away.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!